# Usage of Observer pattern : update() method

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

Hi We (a friend an I) have different sources (wikis contents, forums comments, document uploads, RSS sources...) that we want to notify in our future system in different outs : Javascript LIVE PUSH (APE), mail, SMS, telephone, RSS...

We think about GoF Observer design pattern for our implementation.
Is the Observer design pattern a good way to achieve this ?

We think about Observer to put code to format the message to be notified(cf example 1), but maybe we shall return a status to the Observable in order to create the message(cf example 2).
Is it a good practice in regard of the pattern ?

if yes, what is the "real role" of update() (default Observer design pattern method) ? We don't really get it.

We have found this examples on the web (for update() implementation)

1)
 http://gbenoit79.blogspot.com/2011/04/design-pattern-observer.html

```
<?php
(...) 
class ConcreteObserverA implements SplObserver
{
    public function update(SplSubject $subject)
    {
        echo 'ConcreteObserverA received: ' . $subject->getVariable() . "\n";
    }
}
(...)
```

2)
http://www.minte9.com/kb/php-observer-pattern-example-php-programming-advanced-i1365

```
<?php
(...)
  class DriverObserver implements Observer{
    public function update(Observable $subject) {
      if ($subject->driven_hours >= 8) {
        $subject->need_sleep = 1;
      } else {
        $subject->need_sleep = 0;
      }
    }
  }
(...)
```

Are they both valids ?

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, it is not easy to say if Observer pattern is a good solution, however it might be a valid one.
Observer is an object observing other objects, which are called subjects. When a change happens in some subject, it notifies its observers about the update of its state.
To your example:
Your subjects are wikis contents, forums comments, document uploads, RSS sources... and your observers are Javascript LIVE PUSH (APE), mail, SMS, telephone, RSS...
You should write an abstract class for subjects that should hold collection of Observer objects, ahve methods to add to that collection, remove from it and some methods to choose which observers to notify. Concrete implementations of Observable would than call update on chosen observers with some message data as arguments. Than you need an Observer interface which will have update method which is called when subjects get updated. Concrete implementations would than in that update method send e-mails, push to the web or unregister themselves, whatever.
After this is coded, you initialize the communication by creating Observers, than subjects and adding observers to subjects.